# Who has created a namespace and have access to it

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to understand who has created a namespace and who has access to a specific namespace in Openshift.

This is specifically required as would require to block access and be very selective about access.

Answer (score 2):

Who has created a specific namespace in OpenShift, can be found checking the parent Project annotations:

```
$ oc describe project example-project 
Name:           example-project
Created:        15 months ago
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        alm-manager=operator-lifecycle-manager.olm-operator
                    openshift.io/display-name=Example Project
                    openshift.io/requester=**here is the username**
...
```

Who has access to a specific namespace: depends on what you mean by this. The oc client would allow you to review privileges for a given verb, in a given namespace, ... something like this:

```
$ oc adm policy who-can get pods -n specific-namespace
resourceaccessreviewresponse.authorization.openshift.io/<unknown> 

Namespace: specific-namespace
Verb:      get
Resource:  pods

Users:  username1
        username2
...
        system:admin
        system:kube-scheduler
        system:serviceaccount:default:router
        system:serviceaccount:kube-service-catalog:default
Groups: system:cluster-admins
        system:cluster-readers
        system:masters
```